# Adicionar e remover inputs jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
    <div class="row" id="dep">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do Dependente" id="dependente[]" name="dependente[]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="adicionar_dependente"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E tenho o seguinte jQuery:

```
$("#adicionar_dependente").click(function(){
    var campos_novos = "<div class='col-md-10' id='dep_fc' style='margin-top: 5px;'><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Nome do Dependente' id='dependente[]' name='dependente[]'></div><div class='col-md-2' id='dep_fc' style='margin-top: 5px;'><button class='btn btn-primary' type='button' id='deletar_dependente'><span class='fa fa-minus'></span></button></div>";
    $("#dep").append(campos_novos);
});

$("#deletar_dependente").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('#dep_fc').remove();
});
```

Para adicionar, adiciona normalmente as linhas dentro da div, mas para remover, não funciona. Alguém pode me dizer onde estou errando?

Comment: IDs devem ser únicos no código, prefira `class` nesses casos. Consegue jogar algo funcional no CODEPEN? Seria melhor pra gente testar.

Comment: Quando eu add, o nome do id é dep_fc e quando eu removo tambem...

Comment: Tente com `class` pra ver se muda algo. Se conseguir colocar um demo no http://codepen.io fica fácil de testarmos.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNYvxY

Comment: Ah, tem mais um problema, quando você adiciona um novo #deletar_dependente, creio que o jQuery não vai "valer" para o controle novo.

Comment: Exatamente, ele não vale mesmo, porque eu clico e ele não deleta... Mas postei o codigo la

Comment: vc ta com 2 dep_fc na mesma linha ao inserir, tem mais essa. Provavelmente o mais prático mesmo seria por um onclick dentro da linha, em vez de usar o seletor do jQuery, ou ao acrescentar o controle novo, ir incrementando um numero no ID. ai já resolve o funcionamento e o problema dos IDs repetidos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu vi dois problemas em seu código.

1. Precisa de uma `DIV` para envolver seu campo de texto e seu botão, essa `DIV` será o Parent e precisa ter uma `class` e não um `id`. O `id` não pode repetir na página. Então, como pode ter vários dependentes, então tem que ser `class`.
2. Objetos criados dinamicamente não irá funcionar a função do `onClick` que você define para o botão. É preciso delegar essa função para o `document`, e o `document` passa para o botão que será criado.

```js
$("#adicionar_dependente").click(function() {
  var campos_novos = "<div class='dep_fc'><div class='col-md-10' style='margin-top: 5px;'><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Nome do Dependente' id='dependente[]' name='dependente[]'></div><div class='col-md-2' id='dep_fc' style='margin-top: 5px;'><button class='btn btn-primary remove' type='button' >Remove</button></div></div>";
  $("#dep").append(campos_novos);
});

$(document).on('click', 'button.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('div.dep_fc').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
  <div class="row" id="dep">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do Dependente" id="dependente[]" name="dependente[]">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="adicionar_dependente">ADD</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, é isso, ajustei aqui no meu e deu certinho... E entendi a questão. Muito obrigado!